# Best approximation of an arbitrary matrix by a distance matrix

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, quadratic-programming

A [distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix) $D$ is a $n\times n$ matrix obtained by computing the pair-wise distances $D_{ij} = \text{dist}(x_i, x_j)$ between a collection of points $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ in some metric space. Due to the [metric-axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)), the matrix $D$ satisfies the properties:

1. $D_{ii} = 0$ for all $i$
2. $D_{ij} > 0$ if $i\neq j$
3. $D_{ij} \le D_{ik}+D_{kj}$ for all $k$ (triangle inequality)

Let $\mathfrak D$ be the set of all $n\times n$ distance matrices. Given an arbitrary matrix $\widetilde{D} $, I want to find

$$ \min_{D \in \mathfrak D} \|\widetilde{D} -D\|_\text{F} $$

Are there any results similar to the [Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem) for this problem? And what if we assume that $\widetilde D$ already satisfies (1) and (2)?

Comment: Are you willing to use a different distance metric, not necessarily the Frobenius norm?

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing a bit and relaxing the positivity constraints, given a matrix $\mathrm M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, we have the following (convex) quadratic program (QP) in symmetric matrix $\mathrm X \in \mbox{Sym}_n (\mathbb R)$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X - \mathrm M \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \,\mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \leq \mathrm b\\ & x_{ii} = 0\\ & x_{ij} \geq 0\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm A \,\mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \leq \mathrm b$ encapsulates all the triangle inequalities. Note that the original positivity constraints have been replaced by *non-negativity* constraints.

Comment: It would be extremely nice if the feasible region of the QP above were a well-studied polytope.

Comment: You may be interested in the reference I found.

Answer (score 0):

I found an intriguing reference:

[Convex Optimization Euclidean Distance Geometry 2e by Dattorro](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/mybook.html)

In particular Section 7.0.4 mentions this problem.